# Diagram element tooltips in a Nevron diagram

Tags: c#, .net, nevron

I'm trying to find a way to show a tooltip when the user mouses over a particular diagram element of a Nevron diagram.

Far as I can tell, the NDiagramElement itself doesn't support tooltips. I've tried creating a label and showing it at the mouse position and played around with the System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip class (giving it the form or the control containing the diagram as the tooltip anchor point, since Nevron's classes aren't based on Control). Nothing has worked so far.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

P.S. I'm using .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick:

`someShape.StyleSheet.Style.InteractivityStyle = new NInteractivityStyle("Tooltip text");`